# Is puppy a synonym of dog?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, terminology, resources

I'm a bit confused as to why some thesauruses, e.g. Oxford Dictionaries, state that *puppy* is a synonym of *dog*. To me they are related but not a synonym.

> **dog**
>
> 1. hound, canine, mongrel, cur, tyke;
>      male dog;
>      bitch, pup, **puppy**, whelp
>      *informal*: doggy, pooch, mutt
>      *Australian informal*: mong, bitzer
>      <sub>[ENGLISH THESAURUS](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/dog)</sub>

Can anyone shed some light on the matter please?

Comment: Are you sure you know what a thesaurus offers? It is not usually exact synonyms.

Comment: I know, but by definition is it a synonym?

Comment: A *puppy* is also a dog, just a smaller and younger version. I imagine puppy is also synonymous with *off-spring* But that doesn't mean I call a baby bear a *puppy*.

Comment: As Tim notes, the list of words you got was from a thesaurus, listing closely related words. A synonym are usually considered to be a mostly good enough replacement, not just possible alternatives. So, no, 'puppy' is not considered a synonym of 'dog'. By the way, there are no exact synonyms.

Comment: My 6th grade teacher pounded into my head the fact that a synonym is a word that means ALMOST the same as the word it's supposedly a synonym of.

Comment: It's funny, I had once considered posting a question here:  What is the cutesy-affectionate term for dog: Rabbit <=> Bunny; Cat <=> Kitty; Dog <=> ?????  Then I realized, the answer is "puppy."  Yes, the original meaning was dog less than roughly one year of age, but today many people refers to their dogs (*Who's my good puppy?  You're my good puppy. Yes, you are.*) as puppy for the dog's entire life.

Comment: To be exact, "puppy" is a _hyponym_ and "dog" is the corresponding _hypernym_. Canine in turn is the hypernym of dog (wolves are also canines). Note that not all dogs are puppies, but neither are all dogs bitches. IOW,  the list given is anything but an exact list of synonyms.

Comment: @cobaltduck Interestingly, humans have bred dogs to make them more and more "puppy-like" over time - that's why dogs have such big eyes and floppy ears for example; both are signs of an *immature* dog/wolf. So with respect to their dogly ancestors, modern dogs really are puppies, in a sense.

Comment: How come your question doesn't also ask about "bitch" and "whelp" that are listed right next to "puppy" and are (in my experience) rarely, if ever, used to refer to just any dog (e.g., I never hear "bitch" used for a male dog)? On the other hand, I hear people calling their fully grown dog their "puppy" all the time.

Comment: @cobaltduck The equivalent of "kitty" would, of course, be "doggy" or "doggie", which is also mentioned in the thesaurus quoted above.

Comment: My advice, use a good dictionary as  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com, and not a thesaurus giving variants of a word.

Comment: Also of note. That 'Australian slang' is not used in Australia.

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that _there's no such thing as a synonym_. If two words did in fact mean the exact same thing people would start to use them differently and give them different shades of meaning, and they wouldn't be exact synonyms any more.

Comment: @HotLicks My sixth-grade teacher told my parents I was a mouthy brat. For some reason, my parents  found that humorous. I've always rebelled against authority, including my parents, but on this occasion they happened to get it right.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Synonyms aren't only words that mean the exact same thing.  They may be words that mean approximately the same thing.  Moreover, many do call their adult dogs their "puppy," just like many call other adults their "baby."  Just as "baby" can refer to an adult person, so also can "puppy" refer to an adult dog.

Also, you should note that the entry doesn't cite those words as "synonyms."  Rather, it says they come from a thesaurus.  A thesaurus provides words of similar meaning whose closeness in exact meaning tend to decrease as one moves down a list.  If thesauruses only provided words that meant EXACTLY the same thing, they wouldn't be very helpful as we often use them to try to home in on a better word, one that more exactly says what we mean to say.

Comment: @TimLymington : Thanks.  I corrected the typo.  I also went ahead and corrected a poor construction I had made: just as, so also.

Comment: @TimLymington -- About "homing in," the question in question dates back to 2011. We are nearly 5 years into the future and I'm being persuaded to believe that "hone in" is now the more widely accepted  linguistic (speaking for American English here...)

Comment: My thesaurus lists the words alphabetically, not in decreasing order of closeness.

Comment: @CJ Dennis : I obviously can't speak for all thesauruses, which is why the word "tend."  Thesaurus.com, Collins Dictionary, OED, and many, many others do not alphabetize entries under a given definition of a word but sort them by the strength of their similarity to that definition.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I just wanted to point out that if someone finds a thesaurus with alphabetical entries they shouldn't be too surprised.

Comment: @CJDennis - True.

Answer (score 11):

Because it's useful to list them as such.

*Puppy* is a hyponym of *dog* (a different hyponym in early-modern and contemporary use), not a perfect synonym, but then you already know a perfect word to use when *dog* matches precisely; *dog*.

A thesaurus is useful precisely because it will be a bit "fuzzy" in the synonyms it lists, and so has a chance of providing a better word for your purposes than the one you looked up. Hyponyms and hypernyms are both candidates for this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking why the term ***[puppy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Puppy%20)*** is used to refer to  a small,  young dog, the answer is in its etymology, probably from French "*puppet*" (toy):

> - ***late 15c., "woman's small pet dog," of uncertain origin but likely from Middle French poupée "doll, toy" (see [puppet](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=puppet&allowed_in_frame=0))*** . Meaning shifted from "toy dog" to "young dog" (1590s), replacing Middle English whelp. In early use in English puppet and puppy were not always distinct from each other. Also used about that time in sense of "vain young man." Puppy-dog first attested 1590s (in Shakespeare, puppi-dogges). (Etymonline)

[image] A puppy.

Comment: If you quote explanations of etymology you should always indicate the source.

Comment: Lol at the picture inclusion. Who doesn't want to see a picture of a puppy.

Comment: See also, _puppy love_.

Comment: "If you are asking why the term puppy is used to refer to a small, young dog". The asker isn't. They're asking whether "puppy" and "dog" are synonyms.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Originally the OP *did* ask "why, but the title was edited, and it changed to a simple "yes" or "no" question BUT there's also this afterthought: *Can anyone shed some light on the matter please?* Now, how would you interpret that request?

Answer (score 2):

Every *puppy* is a dog. Some *dogs* (but not all) are *puppies*.

The same way every *woman* is a *human*. Some (but not all) *humans* are *women*.

So *puppy* **might** be a synonym to a *dog* (not in all cases, though).

> I got a new **dog** today. It's so cute!

If and only if said dog is young, one might rephrase:

> I got a new **puppy** today. It's so cute!

Comment: @Mari-LouA And to defend my dignity a bit more I want to point out that I used *woman* because I wished to add to the variety of gender references. And a generic picture of a *human* tends to be a *man*. The intention was good. The delivery clumsy. I appreciate the civil tone of the remark.

Comment: I agree with your answer -- and I like the logic of it.  +1 Sounds like an interesting exchange with Mari-LouA.

Comment: @RichardKayser I'm not sure if you can see all the conversation and editions but basically it was about a very nifty correlation between a female human and a female dog. It was **very** unfortunate and I'm a bit ashamed that I missed it. I mean by no means that women are bitches. Some are. That's true. But so are quite a few men. And that property is beyond the point here. I should have used *mare* but it's not certain that the OP knows it's a girl horsie. Still, a bit funny in retrospective. Thanks for the kind words.